# Spring Integration and HeaderExistsRouter

Tags: spring-integration

Spring Integration 5 here. Looking to define a router in the Java DSL (not XML) that routes messages 2 ways based on the existence of a header:

- if the header exists, go to channel `chan-a`
- else if the header does not exist on the message, go to `error-channel`

At first glance `HeaderValueRouter` seems to be the right tool for the job, but that seems to be just for routing messages for a given header to various channels based on their values. I need something that's more like a...`HeaderExistsRouter`. What are my options here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like "router lambda" and mapping based on its result:

```
.route(Message.class, m -> m.getHeaders().containsKey("foo"),
                        r -> r.channelMapping(true, "chan-a")
                                .channelMapping(false, "error-channel"))
```

However your condition sounds more like a `filter()` which really does its stuff based on `true-false` evaluation. See its `discardChannel()` option for your `error-channel` use-case. The regular `true` result would just simply lead into that `chan-a`. And that's it: doesn't look like we need to bother more complicated router configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion here @Artem, although I now have questions about the Java DSL's filter API, but will ask that in a separate question. Thanks again